# Array and alignment

Tags: indentation, alignment

I'm trying to display a list of values in an array. The top line is fine but when I  include another value it messes up everything. How can I fix this? Basically I want all the values to be equally spaced out, and any that don't fit in the same line go on the next line with the same alignment.
Thank you!
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{parskip} 

\begin{document}

    \centerline{Question 2}

$x = \begin{array}{ccc}
    -1.5  & -0.5 &  -0.804163391778384
\end{array}$

iteration = 

\hspace{8mm}1

$x = \begin{array}{ccc}
-1.5  & -0.5 &  -0.804163391778384 
\\-0.805017312865838
\end{array}$

iteration = 
\hspace{8mm}2



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear what you like to have. I suspect that you looking for the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}

    \centerline{Question 2}

$x = \begin{array}{ccc}
    -1.5  & -0.5 &  -0.804163391778384
\end{array}$

iteration = 

\hspace{8mm}1

$x = \begin{array}[t]{ccc}
-1.5  & -0.5 &  -0.804163391778384  \\
-0.805017312865838  &   &
\end{array}$

iteration =

\hspace{8mm}2
\end{document}
```

[image]

or you may like to have the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}

    \centerline{Question 2}

$x = -1.5 - 0.5 - 0.804163391778384$

iteration \hspace{8mm}1:

$\begin{aligned}
x & = -1.5 - 0.5 - 0.804163391778384  \\
  & = -0.805017312865838
\end{aligned}$

iteration \hspace{8mm}2:
\end{document}
```

According with your added information in question, it seems that you like to have:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

    \centerline{Question 2}

$x = \begin{array}{@{} *{3}{>{$}p{9em}<{$}} }
    -1.5  & -0.5 &  -0.804163391778384
    \end{array}$

iteration = \hspace{8mm}1

$x = \begin{array}[t]{@{} *{3}{>{$}p{9em}<{$}} }
    -1.5  & -0.5 &  -0.804163391778384  \\
    -0.805017312865838  &   &
\end{array}$

iteration = \hspace{8mm}2
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't make my question clear. But this is perfect thank you!

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you explain to me what {@{} *{3}{>{$}p{9em}<{$}} } does please? I'm only a beginner :)

Comment: @AchuanChen, this is columns types specifier. `@{}` remove space on the begin of the first column, `*{3}{...}` means that you have three equal columns, `>{$}` ... `<{$}` that column between is in math mode, `p{9em}` is column type with properties of paragraph and it is is `9em` widem where `em` is width of letter M.